# Checkbox in Android -> running error

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

I'm trying to make a simple app with 3 checkbox and 1 button. I want to make a single toast for each checkbox to see if it is selected or not (click listener), and later to implement for the button a click listener to post a general message to see witch checkbox is selected or not.

If i put the code just with the simple button it runs on my phone (Android version 4.1.1), but if I implement those 3 checkboxex, it crashes (I get a notification like "you app stopped running, click the force close).

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <Checkbox
         android:id= "@+id/ok_checkbox"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/ok_read"
    />
    <Checkbox
         android:id= "@+id/removed_checkbox"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/misspelled"
    />
    <Checkbox
         android:id= "@+id/changed_checkbox"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/changed_read"
    />    
   <Button
         android:id= "@+id/final_click"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/final_click" 
    />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
package com.flowerPower.SpellingTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    private Button finalB;
    private CheckBox ok, changed, removed;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        finalB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.final_click);
        ok = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ok_checkbox);
        changed = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.changed_checkbox);
        removed = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.removed_checkbox);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Your choice is OK",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        changed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Your choice is changed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        removed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Your choice is Windows",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });

    }

 }
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

For checkbox, use setOnCheckedChangeListener() like this-

```
        ok.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
            {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Your choice is OK",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

and similarly for other checkboxes.